# ROUND function and arithmetic overflow

Tags: sql, sql-server, rounding

In MS SQL Server, if I

```
SELECT ROUND(9.4, 0), ROUND(8.6, 0), ROUND(10.6, 0)
```

I unsurprisingly get:

```
9.0 9.0 11.0
```

But if I do

```
SELECT ROUND(9.6, 0)
```

I get:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type numeric.

I know I can just `CAST(9.6 as DECIMAL(10,0))`, but what is going on here?

TIA

Comment: It's rounding from the ones place to the tens place and overflowing because it now has too many significant digits to keep. You need to cast the literal to the type you want before rounding.

Answer (score 6):

SQL takes the first parameter as the datatype, which is, in this case `DECIMAL(2,1)`. The expected outcome, 10.0, should be of type `DECIMAL(3,1)` which is why you get the error.

Try:

```
SELECT ROUND(cast(9.6 as decimal(2,1)), 0)
```

then try:

```
SELECT ROUND(cast(9.6 as decimal(3,1)), 0)
```

Comment: Cool... so `Select round(10.6,0)`  should work,  while `SELECT round(9.6)` will not but `Select round(10.6,0), round(9.6,0)` would!  Implying the order of 10.6 allows 9.6,0 to work!

Comment: you will see the same behavior with `select round(99.6,0)`

Answer (score 4):

When you round up from 9.6 it needs an extra digit to store the number. For literal decimal values you'll have to cast to something wider before doing the round operation. You're probably expecting this to be treated as a floating point value. If you try `round(9.6e, 0)` you'll see a different behavior.

Play around with `sql_variant_property` to see more details. And apparently `ceiling()` and `floor()` don't have the same problem (maybe because they only output integer and zero-scale decimals?). It seems that those two functions keep the same precision but slide the scale up to zero which always leave enough room for the potential new place.